# What are some ways to sanitize an acoustic guitar?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, instrument-cleaning

I'm picking up a used Taylor guitar tomorrow and because of everything that's going on I want to make sure I sanitize it. Would clorox wipes be bad for the guitar? Does anyone have suggestions on what to use? Any help would be great!

Comment: The Virus' denature span seems to depend on the material it's on (if it's there). So I think you can do a quick google search and see if you find anything. Something like "Corona Virus lifetime on Maple Wood" (Or whichever wood your Acoustic is)

Comment: We're told the virus can last for a couple of days on some objects. Leave it for a week?

Comment: Agreed your best bet is to leave at room temp for a week and let everything die naturally. You don’t want to put any alcohol on it and other disinfectants might contain alcohol and also might make it smell funny for ages.

Comment: Have fun with your guitar!

Answer (score 4):

If you are worried about COVID or some other germs I'd just leave it in the garage or basement for 3-5 days or whatever the CDC recommendation is.  A Clorox wipe or other such chemical can and likely WILL ruin the finish!  I have been told by reputable Luthiers that MILD soap and water, immediately wiped off is okay for cleaning an acoustic.  They do get dirty and need to be cleaned like anything else.  You would not want to water log it AND you wold want the towels to be very soft to not scratch the surface, I've heard of people using baby diapers (without chemical treatment).  You would want to be sure that they are wet but completely wrung out so they don't drip.  It is a delicate process and unless you had some training in it you are risking damage.  Always good to practice on a cheap ax first and to get proper advice from a pro.

One thing is for sure, please do not wipe it down with bleach, or any other disinfectant wipe.  Just quarantine it for the recommended time and leave it at that.  If you are really worried about getting something off it then don't get it.  Wait until the COVID smoke clears (hopefully some day soon).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I would use Bleach or alcohol. As I understand it ultra-violet light sanitizes and destroys the virus, so I'd be inclined to leave it in a sunny place for a while, while making certain that it doesn't get heated up by too much sun. Excessive heat isn't good for anything that is wooden and glued together. And as an afterthought, you probably should sterilize the case the guitar comes in also. Or you could just Quarantine the guitar for a couple of weeks. They say that works.